# npm ERR A complete log of this run can be found in

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sass

I was watching a tutorial on sass and I got stuck in this part , im not familiar with npm,nodejs and stuff so idk what i should do !? can u take a look and see why i cant install node-sass?

```
PS D:\NODE-SASS> npm install node-sass
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "node-sass" under anpm ERR! also called "node-sass". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\bla blabla_25_42_696Z-debug.log
PS D:\NODE-SASS> npm install node-sass
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "node-sass" under a package
npm ERR! also called "node-sass". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!  c:/bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This text clearly states that you gave the same name to your project in `package.json` as the name of this package.

> also called "node-sass". Did you name your project the same
> npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?

Rename your project in `package.json` and maybe a folder itself not to confuse it with this package

Comment: Changing `name` attribute? No problem until you wish to turn it into a package on `npmjs.com` and publish it there.

Answer (score -2):

You should rename your project name in package.json file and try again. install  package that you want to install. All of them must be OK

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).